# react native webview check the url before load

Tags: android, ios, reactjs, react-native, webview

I know the method `onShouldStartLoadWithRequest` exists for only ios but is there anything equivalent for android? I need to check the url before the webview loads. I know `onNavigationStateChange` and `onLoadStart` gets called initially but i need something even before this.

Comment: This is just an idea and I'm not sure if it is going to work. What you can do is to inject some javascript to webwiew that listens some event like [`onbeforeunload`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onbeforeunload) and then use `onMessage` to notify react-native about the change.

Answer (score 0):

You can set a webViewClient tpo your webView object and override `shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request)` and get the url like `request.getUrl()`

Comment: Nice thank you! how would i go about grabbing the react-native's webView object in my java code? @cherif